# ExtJS 2.2 openlayers lightbox popup stopped working - error in CGI script

Tags: apache, extjs, cgi, openlayers

I have an old GIS website with OpenLayers 2.7, Geoserver, running ExtJS 2.2 and a lightbox.js. This has been working fine. I can click on a location and fire up a lightbox popup. This has suddenly stopped working. I click a location but and a short spinning wheel so I can see something is happening but no popup. Any idea where I start to search for errors? I get no output in console. Here is my website: http://kulturminnekart.no/ostfold/. When you zoom in and click a marker it should show a popup utilizing the lightbox.js.

I know this is very old but I have never had resources to upgrade to newer ExtJS.

I have an index.html and app.js. Also I include OpenLayers, Mapfish and ExtJS. I have another site running almost the same code so I suspect some upgrade of apache or other software may have caused this but I have no idea where to start looking.

Comment: The network log on the console suggests it's making a WMS GetFeatureInfo request via a proxy, but when I open the url it looks like the server is serving the proxy script instead if running it.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am at something here. I had standard OS X apache and I think this happened when I installed httpd with brew. I had before cgi-scripts here:

Comment: Thanks, I think I am at something here. I had standard OS X apache and I think this happened when I installed httpd with brew. I had before cgi-scripts here: **/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables** but my httpd.conf now points to **/usr/local/var/www/cgi-bin* . So I moved my cgi script to the new cgi-bin but no more luck. How do I check that httpd is running CGI? I suspect something in my httpd.conf needs tweaking? When I try the cgi in a browser I only get the text here:  http://borchbio.no/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi

Comment: It seems cgi is not executed. How do I fix that?  Check http://borchbio.no/cgi-bin/first.cgi

Comment: I suggest you add more tags to the question (or start another one) as the problem isn't with ExtJS or OpenLayers and people following those are unlikely to have an answer.

Comment: @Mike I solved this now thanks to you talking time to look at it. Indeed the cgi script failed to load. And any cgi scripts failed to load. First I fixed mod_cgi to work on Apache. Then I had to do some permission searching since I got permission error. All is working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the click on a marker was doing a WMS GetFeatureInfo request via a proxy (proxy.cgi). Thanks to @Mike I was on a track to debug why cgi was not working. So the solution was to get mod_cgi working correctly on Apache 2.4 and then adjusting the permissions on cgi-bin.